# How to make the textfield in the uisearch bar display on the top instead of center?

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar

I am trying to extend height of the `UISearchBar` when I start to editing the Search Bar content. I am performing following code in the `UISearchBarController`.

```
func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    customSearchBar.showsCancelButton = true
    customDelegate.didStartSearching()

    var newFrame:CGRect = customSearchBar.frame;
    newFrame.size = CGSizeMake(customSearchBar.frame.width, customSearchBar.frame.height + 35);
    customSearchBar.frame = newFrame;
}
```

However, when I not extend the length it will work fine, after I extend the length, the `UITextField` gets auto aligned Vertical to the Center of the frame, which I don't want to happen.

[image]

How i am able force the textfield to show in its original location?

Comment: What's the original location that you want? Also what is customSearchBar? Is it same as searchBar?

Comment: are you using constraints ?

Comment: no...the textfield itself is default..

Answer (score 0):

You probably shouldn't be doing this, but you can change:

```
var newFrame:CGRect = customSearchBar.frame
    newFrame.size = CGSizeMake(customSearchBar.frame.width, customSearchBar.frame.height + 35)
    customSearchBar.frame = newFrame
```

To:

```
var newFrame:CGRect = customSearchBar.frame
    newFrame.size = CGSizeMake(customSearchBar.frame.width, customSearchBar.frame.height + 35);
    newFrame.origin = CGPoint(x: 10, y: 10)
    customSearchBar.frame = newFrame
```

And see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

The textfield and the search bar control is a single control. If you change the frame of the search bar the text field within it automatically vertically centers itself. Instead if you want the behaviour that you are looking for then you should put the search bar inside another view as a subview and then change the height of that view. You can use auto layouts to position the searchBar within that parent view.

Comment: Note that you can always [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/35507102/edit) your answer; please avoid posting several times on the same page. Thanks.